# ISP-restricted VPN on Android

Tags: privacy, android, vpn, proxy, vps

How to connect to VPN service on Android via its app if it's restricted by state ISPs, but you're able to connect via cloud VPS network outside the state

My idea is about concepts in general:

- you have some Android 9+ device
- you have some VPN (and like CloudFlare WAPR 1.1.1.1) apps
- VPN apps are blocked entirely by government censorship, deep packet inspection (DPI) and other network traffic inspecting solutions.

You might be able to set up some VPN/proxy/DNS on cloud VPS outside the state WAN. But a problem here is these VPS are affiliated with local companies who get paid with local currency, they're under local law and obviously "listen" to all traffic which is going through like regular ISP, due to law.

This is the reason why you need "clear", "direct" and trusted VPN and why basic VPS as a proxy or VPN client on the VPS side is not a solution, but an implementation of a man-in-the-middle attack.

A problem is about how it can be implemented on different levels.
You have a point about using only service-issued applications and avoiding some more DIY-ways like using OpenVPN/Wireguard, because it doesn't offer all possibilities and security.

On the other side, you can't establish multiple VPN connections simultaneously due to Android architecture.

But theoretically, you can set up a proxy on the LTE APN (carrier access point) properties level or Wi-Fi connection properties level, or establish connection to VPS on the router.

Setting up some hypothetical proxy on the level of LTE APN is preferable.

I guess you can't connect to VPS local network directly because firstly you should connect to carrier/ISP network and pass through it. But on which level you'll be able to do this and how?

I can't even google some good stuff about connecting via carrier APN proxy (possibly it won't work here at all).

So, a problem is how to connect to VPS local network on the first step and then connect via VPS network to VPN service and implement it on Android (and even iOS if the solution shares common principles). Of course, I'm interested also about implementation on Windows/Linux clients. Possibly, it will be easier to get static IP issued by local ISPs, set up VM on the home pc, establish a connection to VPS via this local server, and then connect both PC-client and Android client to this local server with previously configured VPN connection on the local server side... Any ideas?

And yes, let's guess that VPN service app DOESN'T provide a proxy option (like dear ProtonVPN)

Comment: I edited the question to keep it to a single question and to remove the hidden text (some of which aren't applicable to the question at hand).

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking when you seem to answer your own question. If you can't use the built-in app, then use an 3rd party VPN app and connect outside of the jurisdiction. What additional problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @schroeder i'm trying to connect outside of the jurisdiction and it requres connect to VPS before, because almost all VPNs restricted or will be due to known endpoint list. There is only way to connect inside some VPS network, but i didn't figure out how to tmplement it technically, because... what i'm trying to reach out? nested VPN? or proxied VPN? and is it possible in a way i described or there is the only proper way to get it

Comment: and @schroeder , about hidden text. I add this to avoid some ideas, to tell why this or this not possible

Comment: But the answer is to run a VPN server on a VPS in the jurisdiction and install a VPN client on your phone. You've mentioned all that. I'm not seeing the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: For now, i suceed to do it on PC using OpenVPN over socks-proxy, using shadowsocks project.

Partially suceed in Android. I get shadowsocks proxy and able to connect to VPN simultaneously.

Still not able to use official apps like ProtonVPN or CloudFlare 1.1.1.1 as is via socks at entire system level

Found that OpenVPN client on Android doesn't support local socks proxy ics-openvpn trying to login to local shadowsocks proxy (it doesn't have credentinals) with VPN credentinals

Comment: Follow-up question on Android.SE: [VPN over proxy (global)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/251118/44325)